# check/uncheck checkbox based on another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at item 4197593 How to check uncheck a checkbox based on another checkbox and copied the code from the demo to my webpage. When I open the page I get a java error - the yellow triangle bottom left hand corner.
The error only occurs when I add in this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    //bind event to checkbox 

  $("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click', function(){
    var $t = $(this),         
    val = $t.val(),         
    key = val.charAt(val.length-1);      
    // check if element is checked     
    if($t.val() == 'la'+key && $t.is(':checked')) {       
      $("#lists_"+key).attr('checked', true);     
    }     
    else if($t.val() == 'la'+key){       
      $("#lists_"+key).attr('checked', false);     
    }   
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

I am adding this to a php page:

```
<?php
include('header3.html');
$Fullname = $_SESSION['membername'];

include('connectdb.php');
?>
*the above javascript is added in here*
<style type="text/css">
```

Hope someone can help me here as I am not too bright on java.

Comment: Have you included jQUery or some other library? `$` isn't built-in function and is commonly defined in jQuery or such libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Huh? I do not see any **java** in your code, only a mix of **HTML** and **javascript**.

Moreover, you should learn the basics of javascript rather than copy + paste scripts.

For instance, the code you have looks like it needs the jQuery javascript library...

Doing what you are asking in plain javascript is as trivial as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="original" onchange="update()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="other"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){
        var original = document.getElementById('original');
        var other = document.getElementById('other');
        original.checked = other.checked;
    }
</script>
```

**Caution**

You should rename function `update` better or even better, make use of [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript) bound to the [checkbox's `change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: @mplungjan +1 There was an interesting discussion about, but I forgot the details.

Comment: Likely a jQuery discussion about the clicked attribute

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery, so you need to include the jQuery .js too