# checkbox updating another checkbox on different form

Tags: javascript, checkbox

my first javascript is not working, hope you can help.

I am trying to make a checkbox on one form check a checkbox on another form. This is based on this link: [check/uncheck checkbox based on another checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8985557/5037035)

Here is my simplified code

```
<formname="A"
action="WebPage.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="Aa" onchange="update()" value="Aa"/>Aa
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){
        var original = document.getElementById('Aa');
        var other = document.getElementById('Ba');
        original.checked = other.checked;
    }
</script>    
</form>
<formname="B"
action="WebPage.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="Ba" value="Ba"/>Ba
</form>
```

This is not working. Checking Aa does nothing to Ba.

In case I am going down the wrong path, if this can work, then I will change it so checking Aa unchecks Ba, Bb, Bc, and other checkboxes on form B. Then I want to add a function on form B so that checking any one or all checkbox(es) there will cause Aa to be unchecked.

I am at the very beginning of website design, so I appreciate your advice on the best direction to go.

Thanks, Dan

Comment: You are trying to access elements by id.So add id in both checkbox. e.g.,  <input type="checkbox" id="Aa" name="Aa">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no id property for the checkbox elements, also you need to change the assignment to `other.checked = original.checked;`

```html
<form name="A"
      action="WebPage.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Aa" id="Aa" onchange="update()" value="Aa"/>Aa
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){
      var original = document.getElementById('Aa');
      var other = document.getElementById('Ba');
      other.checked = original.checked;
    }
  </script>    
</form>
<form name="B"
      action="WebPage.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Ba" id="Ba" value="Ba"/>Ba
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function update(){

    var original = document.getElementById("Aa");
    var other= document.getElementById("Ba");

    if (original .checked == true )
      other.checked = true;
    else
      other.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="A" action="WebPage.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="Aa" id="Aa" onchange="update()" value="Aa"/>Aa
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function update(){

    var original = document.getElementById('Aa').checked ;
    var other= document.getElementById('Ba').checked ;

    if (original == true ){
      other = true;
    }else{
      other = false;}
   }
    </script>    
</form>
<form name="B"action="WebPage.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Ba" id="Ba" value="Ba"/>Ba
</form>
```